# Speech Verification API by Microsoft

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We have [Face API](https://www.projectoxford.ai/face) in Project Oxford provided by Microsoft, which verifies the faces of two persons. In the same way is there Speech Verification API provided by Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is a new feature provided by Project Oxford. Please check [Speaker Recognition APIs](https://www.projectoxford.ai/spid).